# Multivariate equality of variances

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, heteroscedasticity

I have 2 datasets $X_1,X_2$: $n$ and $m$ vectors of $l$ length. The distribution of each point in dataset has finite variance and mean, for simplicity, for $X_j$ and coordinate $i$ the distribution is $\mathcal N (\mu_{ji}, \sigma_{ji})$.

What if I want to answer the question "if variance in $X_1$ is greater than in $X_2$"? I was able to make a scatterplot of variances. I was also able to make the paired test for difference, comparing 2 vectors of variances from different datasets, but comparing in this way does not take SE of variance into account. How to answer the question correctly?

UPD: More clear explanation using the real example from the paper http://www.nature.com/articles/srep13107 , figure 2. The authors just plot standard deviations one against another and conclude that one dataset is more variable. Is there a formal way to check this?

[image]

UPD2: The example of the problem: we have human genome and a fixed set positions in human genome ((chr1, 500), (chr1, 700), ..., (chr2, 1050), ... ). When we sequence genome, we divide it into small parts and read each small part separately. Thus we have two numbers for each of the positions: $n$, number of times this position was read, and $m \leq n$ - number of times this position was changed ($n - m$ - position remained unchanged). In practice people work with $m/n$ - percentage of times the position was changed. The distribution of $n, m$ can be considered as Beta Binomial. The question is: having 2 cohorts, i.e. Old and Young humans, how to say if one cohort has bigger variance in terms of $m/n$ - percentage of position changed with the age?

Comment: Have you heard of the F test for testing equally of variances or more robust versions such as Levene's test.  A search of the site and a search on Google would yield a lot of useful information. But I may be misinterpreting you because the Xi s are vectors and the terminology is puzzling. When you say "distribution of each point in the dataset has a finite variance and mean" do you mean that each component of the vector is a random variable with a finite mean and variance. Also if X1 and X2 are vectors of random variables it wouldn't make sense to ask which vector has the greater variance,

Comment: @MichaelChernick I am sorry for my bad explanations. I mean exactly that each component of a vector have a well defined distribution. $X_1$ and $X_2$ are 2 sets of samples from 2 vectors of random variables. In other words, I am looking for a multi-dimensional F test. F test can be applied for each component separately, but I would like to answer if variance in $X_1$ is bigger in general than in $X_2$ (probably it can be reformulated as 'for more components than expected by chance').

Comment: Are the 2 sets paired? Ie, can you say that datum 1 in set 1 corresponds to datum 1 in set 2 (perhaps they were measured on the same study unit)?

Comment: @gung sure, they are paired, so it is possible to make a scatter plot

Comment: What are the variables? Where do they come from? Can you provide more concrete information about the study?

Comment: @gung tried to explain it in UPD2 with the real example from the study.

Comment: That's helpful. Are the n's (number of reads) the same in all cases?

Comment: @gung for simplicity we can say yes for each position $i$ we have constant $n_i$. Actually no, $n$ can be considered as generated from Poisson distribution with constant $\lambda_i$ for each position $i$ within the genome, but since the changes are typically huge (as shown on the plots), the simplest solution will be good.

Comment: In some sense it'd be simpler, but I don't think it'd be better. It isn't necessarily difficult to deal w/ that. Do you know the n for each data point?

Comment: @gung can estimate it from data, the amount of samples in Old/Young cohort allows to do this quite accurately.